# "Missing Template" when manually creating views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, routes

I create controller in controllers/admin/orders.rb

```
def index
    @pre_orders = Order.all
    @orders = Kaminari.paginate_array(@pre_orders).page(params[:page]).per(20)

  end
```

I have such route:

```
namespace :admin do
    # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
    # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
    resources :orders
  end
```

And view in views/admin/orders/index.html.haml

But when i go to ....3000/admin/orders i get
Template is missing

```
Missing template admin/orders/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in: * "/*******/app/views" * "/home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/kaminari-0.14.1/app/views" * "/home/pavel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
```

Comment: check the template has read permission. everything else looks fine.

Comment: @HungryCoder yes, it have only read... but still doesn't work for some reasons( but create etc actions works